# advanced custom filed (ACF) front end form not sending email.

Tags: php, forms, email, advanced-custom-fields

I am using acf form to add events to my site. it is adding event perfectly . I am try to send email when user submit email. But mail not working. here is the code I am using

```
    <div class="event_forn_holder">


            <?php acf_form(array(


                'post_id'       => 'new_post',
                'new_post'      => array(
                    'post_type'     => 'events',
                    'post_status'       => 'pending'
                ),

                'html_updated_message'  => '<div id="event_message" class="alert alert-success"><p>Event has been submitted for review. Thanks</p></div>',
                'post_title' => false,
                'uploader' => 'basic',
            'field_groups' => array(3236),
                'submit_value'      => 'Submit Event'
            )); ?> 





            </div>
```

Here is the code I am using in functions.php

```
add_action('acf/save_post', 'acf_my_save_post');

function acf_my_save_post( $post_id ) {

    // bail early if not a contact_form post
    if( get_post_type($post_id) !== 'events' ) {

        return;

    }


    // bail early if editing in admin
    if( is_admin() ) {

        return;

    } 


    // vars
    $post = get_post( $post_id );


    // get custom fields (field group exists for content_form)
    $name = get_field('event_name', $post_id);
    $email = get_field('your_email', $post_id);


    // email data
    $to = 'mail@yahoo.com';
    $headers = 'From: ' . $name . ' <' . $email . '>' . "\r\n";
    $subject = $post->post_title;
    $body = $post->post_content;


    // send email
    wp_mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just compared it with a function I have that's almost exactly the same, except it actually does work and send me the email. The only difference I see is that in mine I have the $body variable starting with "\r\n" and then the content.

```
    $body = "\r\n" . $post->post_content;
```

Other than that maybe it's going to spam. Or maybe you have some other plugin or code somehow conflicting with it.